# Auto-login LXDE

Tags: login-screen, lxde, auto-login

Dears,

I'm looking for a way to automatic login into LXDE GUI. I do not want to disable window manager but I want to start without a need to login without any login screen - just go directly into LXDE.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do it for a Lubuntu install.  If you have installed LXDE over a different system, you may have to modify it.

Create or edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

Add the following to this file

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=your-username-here
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=Lubuntu
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case I did modify /etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf file: "autologin=root". Now I have automatic login,

Comment: If this helped you, please upvote it and/or mark it as correct by clicking the gray check mark.  It will increase both our reputation scores.

Answer (score 0):

For Debian, it is:

```
[Seat:*]
pam-service=lightdm
pam-autologin-service=lightdm-autologin
autologin-user=TYPE-YOUR-USERNAME-HERE
autologin-user-timeout=0
session-wrapper=/etc/X11/Xsession
greeter-session=lightdm-greeter
```

(add this to the end of the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file)

[Source](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=673551&sid=ea015906d13865e8fdf497ba869c2a81#p673551)